# Dynamic images (ex. live countdown clock) in HTML emails

Tags: php, html, email

I've been trying to figure out how companies like GAP, Starbucks, Office Depot etc... have been able to send emails with a live countdown timer in them. Obviously, javascript won't run on emails and neither will flash. Can PHP do such thing?

Here's a sample of what Starbucks sent me this morning.
http://ink1003.com/p/lp/4a4d39bdf193841d.png?mi_t=BQsyGEAJvkyvB8vVgWNsoVfTVZ

The closest I've seen to handling this is a paid service http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2010/12/dynamic-time-based-images/

Comment: It's an animated GIF. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Won't an animated GIF reset to the first frame each time you reload it? The example above remembers the state each time it reloads.

Comment: It seems the server generates a customer version of the image on the fly for every load.

Comment: It's an animated png, not a gif.

Comment: I have been task with making something like this at my company, I managed to find a php script that does exactly this, but the problem was the script was generating high load on a server.

Answer (score 5):

It's a PNG (although animated PNGs don't work on some browsers...this one somehow manages the trick).

Some of these large companies buy the service from http://movableink.com

Check out lastminute.com's recent clock http://www.movable-ink-4805.com/p/lp/aad7a5df0fdfe6be.png

It runs for 1 minute. The expectation is nobody will look at it for longer.

By the way, you may want to check out the Open Source project https://github.com/Omgitsonlyalex/EmailCountdown

Answer (score 1):

May be it's an animated image and there's a server side script that is either replacing the image with one that has X frames less, or is deleting frames. The only other thing I can think of is a timer and iframe, but dunno whether iframes will work from within an e-mail..

Cheers!

P.S. No, Php can't do such a thing - it's being executed on the server side before the browser gets the source of the page to be interpreted, so it's virtually no way to interpret it as you interpret JS or html.

Comment: the example wasn't done with iframes. In fact iframes won't work 100% in emails. <http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/> thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways this can be done.  Using PHP and making a subtle change in apache you can load an image dynamically as `domain.com/whatever.gif` once this is known the rest is just a matter of coding the image its self and optimizing the code so that a new image is not needed for every access, only when there is a new time.

I am sure the specifics could be knocked out in a short time.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right about apache changing the request to a gif (or png) instead of php. Do you think PHP GD can do this?

Comment: I have not personally created an animated GIF with GD.  It is my understanding that it does not support animation.  A brief search turned up a number of classes that were created to take images and mash them together into an animation.  one such class is at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html

Comment: a tutorial using `imagick` is at the bottom of this page http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Imagick.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real answer but I do have a hint.  You might see if you can find someone familiar with the Zaplets technology. They're a company from 2000 or so that was founded in Austin by the Reactivity team.  At the core of their product was the idea of sending emails that had dynamic html in them so that when the user looked at the email they would see the latest content.  For instance, you could send out a survey asking people to vote for something, and the latest voting tally was always shown in the email.

Anyway, if you can track down someone from the Reactivity team you can probably find your answer.  Also their tech was apparently bought by Xobni so if you can find those guys they could probably tell you too.

Answer (score 0):

Check this  https://litmus.com/community/learning/27-how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-your-email. This works by taking a PNG and using a PHP script to create a looping GIF counting down to a time.

It takes a flat PNG and super imposes the countdown based on your variables in the PHP script onto it.

When a user receives it in their inbox, they'll see it loop for 1 minute and reset. However, if they leave the email and return it will have adjusted to countdown again.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t general like to reference specific products in answers, but [gifcountdown.com](http://gifcountdown.com/) do it well. Their specific technique is a server that can hold open an HTTP connection and generate a GIF on a frame-by-frame basis without closing the connection. The initial settings are defined by the URL you use to access the image, the server then generates and sends a new frame once a second until the user closes the connection. For example, here’s a countdown to New Year (GMT) 2014 from their service.

[Gif countdown example http://gifcountdown.com/europe-london/1420070400/141414/0f0f0f/aaaaaa/fdfdfd/faedad/true/counter.gif](http://gifcountdown.com/europe-london/1420070400/141414/0f0f0f/aaaaaa/fdfdfd/faedad/true/counter.gif)